# Integral of a distribution function

Tags: probability, random-variables

I am attempting to prove the following identity for the random variable R defined on ($ -\infty $, $ +\infty $). Upon attempting to integrate by parts I run into an indeterminate form. I am not sure how to proceed to prove the identity.

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{z}\ F(r)\,\mathrm dr = \int_{-\infty}^{z}\mathbf (z-r)f(r)\,\mathrm dr = \int_{-\infty}^{z}\mathbf (z-r)\,\mathrm dF(r),
$$

Where F(r) is the distribution function which is defined as follows (f being the density function for R):
$$
\ F(x)=\,\mathrm P(R\leqslant x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}\ f(R)\,\mathrm dR\
$$

Comment: Which is the indeterminate form? I do not see it, can you tell me please. Thanks/

Comment: when integrating by parts, you get infinity times zero.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \int_{-\infty}^z F(r)dr = \int_{-\infty}^z\int_{-\infty}^rf(u)dudr
= \int_{-\infty}^z\int_u^zdrf(u)du = \int_{-\infty}^z(z - u)f(u)du$$

Comment: How did you change the bounds of integration? I am not following what you did in the second equality..

Comment: @Qwert it might help if you visualize or draw out the region of integration in the plane

Comment: Usually when I doing this, I always bear in mind the inequality governing the integration limits: $-\infty < u < r < z $ where $u, r$ are the variables to integrate with. Depending on the order of integration, the variable that integrate first will choose the "tightest" bound. So if I integrate with respect to $r$ first, then I integrate from $u$ to $z$; after $r$ is integrated out, we can integrate $u$ from $-\infty$ to $z$. Hope this help.